# Тень от box-shadow не видна, z-index не помогает

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gerbera";
  src: url("/fonts/gerbera.otf");
}
section.topnav {
  background-color: #1eab9e;
  padding: 12px 0 0 0;
  ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      a {
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 35px;
        font-family: "Gerbera", sans-serif;
      }
    }
  }
}

section.nav {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 5;
  img.logo {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      a.menu {
        color: #5a5a5a;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 35px;
        font-family: "Gerbera", sans-serif;
      }
      a.register {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: rgb(241, 105, 80);
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(159, 155, 155, 0.004);
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Gerbera", sans-serif;
        padding: 7.5px 15px 7.5px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: .25s;
        &:hover {
          transition: .25s;
          background-color: #e44426;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

section.main {
  background: url("../img/main.jpg");
  padding: 180px 0 220px 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

@import "media.scss";
```

HTML:

```
<section class="topnav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Положения проведения акции</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Критерии конкурсных работ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="menu" href="#">цель проведения</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu" href="#">кто может принять участие</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu" href="#">положения</a></li>
                <li><a class="register" href="#" >регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Вот так это должно выглядеть (без отступа)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Задал position: relative; на каждую секцию, проблему решило.

Comment: Могли бы вы дать более развёрнутый ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `position: relative` в `section.main`.Так `z-index` работает только для элементов, у которых значение `position` задано как `absolute`, `fixed` или `relative`.

Answer (score -1):

Уберите @import "media.scss"; в конце css-кода. Как ни странно, если его убираю, то тень появляется.

Comment: Это тут совсем не причём, это подключение сторонних файлов стилей в sass препроцессоре.